# How to run two commands in two separate terminals considering the order of execution, and then repeat the execution of commands in the same terminals?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I need to perform the following scenario using bash script:

1- Run a particular command in terminal 1. This command will launch a particular program that will listen to port x. (i.e. wait)

2- Run a particular command in terminal 2, which will connect to the above port (x) and then execute specific commands located in a gdbinit file.

3- After generating the output from terminal 1, kill both terminals and
then ... repeat (goto 1)

Step 2 must follow step 1 as step 2 will connect to the port opened by step 1.

I attempt to perform this work automatically (n times) through a bash script file.

More:
Is it possible to run a command in an old terminal? I mean, after finishing the first loop, I want to execute the same command (for 2nd time) in that terminal.

Comment: The questions seems XY problem to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also, mentioned gdbinit suggests you're trying to perform some sort of remote debug, or...? Can you be a bit more specific on the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: When it comes to script synchronization, sometimes wait files/pid files are used. Script 1 checks if the file exists and then sleeps before checking again. Script 2 creates the file. This is not the best type of synchronization(better exists and this has issues), but is commonly used.

Comment: Why do the commands need a terminal? Can't you invoke both of them in the background from the same terminal and have them communicate via the port.